# Gremlin 3 Paths with Depth

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am brand new to Gremlin and graph databases in general.  I have been tasked with producing a plan in which to execute a task based on the depth at which the node exists in the subgraph.

So far, I can produce the subgraph and a list of paths based on that subgraph.  I am stuck when I try to add depths to the paths, especially when some nodes exist in multiple paths. You can see here the graph I am testing against:

```
public void generateTestGraph(){
    Vertex web  = this.sqlgGraph.addVertex(T.label, "Server", "name", "WEB");
    Vertex app  = this.sqlgGraph.addVertex(T.label, "Server", "name", "APP1");
    Vertex app2 = this.sqlgGraph.addVertex(T.label, "Server", "name", "APP2");
    Vertex app3 = this.sqlgGraph.addVertex(T.label, "Server", "name", "APP3");
    Vertex sql  = this.sqlgGraph.addVertex(T.label, "Server", "name", "SQL");
    web.addEdge("DEPENDS_ON", app);
    web.addEdge("DEPENDS_ON", app2);
    app.addEdge("DEPENDS_ON", sql);
    app3.addEdge("DEPENDS_ON", sql);
    app2.addEdge("DEPENDS_ON", app3);

    this.sqlgGraph.tx().commit();
}
```

I can produce path lists like so:

```
public void testDepGraph(){
    String name = "SQL";

    Graph subGraph = (Graph) this.sqlgGraph.traversal().V().has("name", name).repeat(__.inE("DEPENDS_ON")
    .subgraph("subGraph").outV()).in("DEPENDS_ON").loops().is(P.gt(50)).cap("subGraph").next();

    Object vl = subGraph.traversal().V().has("name", name).repeat(__.in("DEPENDS_ON")).emit(__.not(__.inE())).path().by("name").toList();
}
```

But, they look like this:

```
{
    ["SQL", "APP1", "WEB"],
    ["SQL", "APP3", "APP2", "WEB"]
}
```

Which is close, but I would like to see the output look like this:

```
{
    0: {"SQL"},
    1: {"APP1", "APP3"},
    2: {"APP2"},
    3: {"WEB"}
}
```

So, my question is:  Can I get the results I want by using Gremlin directly, or will I have to do some post-processing by hand(code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using a single query, but it's pretty complex and might be hard to grasp if you just started to use Gremlin.

```
gremlin> g.V().group("x").
                 by("name").
                 by(out("DEPENDS_ON").values("name").fold()).
           barrier().
           repeat(
             cap("x").unfold().
             filter(select(values).not(unfold().where(without("y")))).
                    select(keys).where(without("y")).
             aggregate("y").
             aggregate("z").
               by(project("a","b").
                    by().
                    by(coalesce(select("z").unfold().select("b").order().by(decr).limit(1).
                                  sack(assign).sack(sum).by(constant(1)).sack(),
                                constant(0))))
           ).cap("z").unfold().group().by(select("b")).by(select("a").fold())
==>[0:[SQL],1:[APP3,APP1],2:[APP2],3:[WEB]]
```

This query creates a dependency map `x` and then loops through the map, picking only those entries that have dependencies to components that were processed in previous iterations. `repeat()` will terminate once there are no unprocessed components left. After each iteration processed components will be stored in a list named `y` and and the same component will be stored as a tuple (together with the iteration index) in a list named `z`.

The list named `z` will eventually be used to create the desired map result, where the iteration index is the map's key and the components are the respective values.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: @daniel , I've finally come around to implementing your answer, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to convert this to the JAVA syntax.  Would you be able to point me somewhere or help me?  I can post a new question if you need.  Thank you.

Comment: Daniel, that is amazing.  So many static imports... Thank you again.